# Предварительное преобразование таблицы в DataTable Shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

Необходимо при выборе магазина(ов) заново отфильтровать исходную таблицу (`SaleData`) по выбранным магазинам в `CheckBoxGroup`, 
затем сгруппировать по дате, посчитать общую сумму необходимого значения, транспонировать и передать в буферную таблицу, которая должна отобразиться в приложении R Shiny.

Как осуществить все эти операции понятно, но как их написать в части r server?

Ниже код приложения:

```
    library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("Прогноз продаж"),

  fluidRow(

    column(1, 
           checkboxGroupInput('Store', 'Магазины', unique(TestData$Store), inline = FALSE))

  ),



  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")

)

server <- function(input, output) {


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    buffer_table  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Приведённого кода недостаточно для воспроизведения описанной ситуации.

Comment: Максимум, что могу добавить так это то что в самой R Studio загружены данные которые после преобразования передаются в таблицу buffer_table.  Есть подозрение, что необходимо сделать функцию которая будет принимать в качестве аргумента вектор выбранных магазинов от checkboxGroupInput, заново фильтровать и преобразовывать данные и перезаписывать в таблицу buffer_table и затем в качестве объекта возвращать новую buffer_table в DT::renderDataTable({
      
  })

Answer (score -1):

Всё решилось добавлением функции, которая принимает выбранные значения из checkboxGroupInput, делает все необходимые преобразования и возвращает новую таблицу:

output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    **filter_Store_function(input$Store)**
  })
}